# repeatedly selected items in list and find the lowest difference based on max-min of list

Tags: python

randomly the elements in a list and then repeatedly find its difference between (max - min) of the randomly selected elements, lastly print out the minimum difference

I think my above almost explained everything but let me rephrase.

I build a code that tries to randomly selected few elements in the list based on the input k. After selecting few of the elements then I will calculate the difference between the max(list) - min(list).

Example;

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

max(a) - min(a) = 4
```

then this value will be saved into a dictionary. However, the dictionary is to store(maybe other method is better or faster).

I will keep on select random elements based on k and find the difference. Lastly, it will compare all these differences and store the LOWEST difference into the dictionary.

```
import random

maximum_dict = dict()
maximum_dict["m"] = 1000000000

def maxMin(k, arr):
    list_temp = random.sample(arr, k)
    maximum = int(max(list_temp) - min(list_temp))
    for x, y in maximum_dict.items():
        while maximum < y:
            if maximum < y:
                maximum_dict["m"] = maximum
            else:
                while maximum > y:
                    list_temp = random.sample(arr, k)
                    maximum = int(max(list_temp) - min(list_temp))
                    if maximum < y:
                        maximum_dict["m"] = maximum


    return maximum

def p():
    print(maximum_dict.values())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [10,100,300,200,1000,20, 30]
    k = 3
    print(maxMin(k, arr))
    p()
```

My current output:

It randomly goes everywhere and it should only be one output because that will be the lowest.

My expected output:

the dictionary = `{"m":20}`

or printed version:

Comment: I am not following, can you please just explain what should be the input and what is the output you expect ?

Comment: The input is an array. The k is 3 means to choose 3 elements from the array. Example, when I use random.sample(arr, k), it will take any random values within length of 3. The output is actually the lowest difference between max(arr) and min(arr). Means, if my new random arr is [10,20,30] then the max(arr) - min(arr) = 20. <--- this is taken as difference. However, I wanted to compare all randoms and find the lowest possible.

Comment: My output should be the lowest difference when inside this [10,100,300,200,1000,20, 30]. We have many combinations, so I wanted it to keep looping and choose random based on the K and then compare it with the previous stored "lowest difference". If current difference > previous lowest different then it will keep looping else it will store the current lowest difference

Comment: For the first case i.e. creating an array of random numbers and then calculating the difference b/w the max and min is fairly easy, but i am still not following your second case. So what should be the output when the input array is [10,100,300,200,1000,20, 30] ?

Comment: Yes, the first case is super easy because I just need to use new_arr =  random.sample(arr, 3) to get the arr and then use create a variable to store max(new_arr) - min(new_arr). Let me explain in more detailed, example, our current first case will only calculate ONE time random and find ONE lowest difference. However, we still have more elements in the list and we can keep doing random picks from the list and then keep calculating the difference. Here, example 1, pick 3 randoms and get one output such as 30. Then example 2, pick 3 randoms and get one output such as 10.

Comment: isnt 10 is more lower than 30? If this is the case, then what I want is to keep on doing random pick from the list and keep on finding the lowest difference for the particular random pick and compare it. we can do 100 times random pick and find 100 lowest difference and then take the lowest among these 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you what you are looking for.

```
from itertools import combinations

arr = [10, 100, 300, 200, 1000, 20, 30]

b = tuple(combinations(arr, 3))

print("The various combinations look like this")
for i in b:
    print(i)

res = [max(i)-min(i) for i in b]
print(
    f"The list shows the difference b/w max and min for every combination\n{res}")
print(f"The lowest difference = {min(res)}")
```

**Output:**

```
The various combinations look like this
(10, 100, 300)
(10, 100, 200)
(10, 100, 1000)
(10, 100, 20)
(10, 100, 30)
(10, 300, 200)
(10, 300, 1000)
(10, 300, 20)
(10, 300, 30)
(10, 200, 1000)
(10, 200, 20)
(10, 200, 30)
(10, 1000, 20)
(10, 1000, 30)
(10, 20, 30)
(100, 300, 200)
(100, 300, 1000)
(100, 300, 20)
(100, 300, 30)
(100, 200, 1000)
(100, 200, 20)
(100, 200, 30)
(100, 1000, 20)
(100, 1000, 30)
(100, 20, 30)
(300, 200, 1000)
(300, 200, 20)
(300, 200, 30)
(300, 1000, 20)
(300, 1000, 30)
(300, 20, 30)
(200, 1000, 20)
(200, 1000, 30)
(200, 20, 30)
(1000, 20, 30)
The list shows the difference b/w max and min for every combination
[290, 190, 990, 90, 90, 290, 990, 290, 290, 990, 190, 190, 990, 990, 20, 200, 900, 280, 270, 900, 180, 170, 980, 970, 80, 800, 280, 270, 980, 970, 280, 980, 970, 180, 980]
The lowest difference = 20

[Process exited 0]
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I am looking for! Thank you so much. I will try to learn from this.

Comment: Actually, I have a question, I thought about using combinations to get all the possible combinations but what about if I wanted it to be randomly picked? Combinations method is a way to solve it and even using randomly picked will still output the same result. However, if I can learn the way to use randomly picked then it will be good as well.

Comment: Please go through itertools documentation, it has some really powerful tools to work with iterables in python. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#module-itertools

Comment: Even that can be achieved but for that I guess you need to know in advance how many combinations of temporary sequences you want to make, i.e. you need to know how many `list_temp = random.sample(arr, k)` such lists do you want to create, and then you can build on with the same logic.

Comment: I see. Alright, thank you so much for the sharing. I understand it now.

Comment: Glad to help !!